# Using foreach to loop if there are more items added

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have this piece of code on my page that is called **menu.php**. It shows all the products inside my database where the user can choose which one to order.

```
$prod_query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblproducts");
$num_rows_prod=mysqli_num_rows($prod_query);

echo "<div class='row'>";

while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($prod_query))
  {
    $ppid=$fetch['p_pid'];
    $pname=$fetch['p_name'];
    $pprice=$fetch['p_price'];
    $pimg='<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($fetch['p_image']). '" width="100%" height="280">';
echo "
<form method='post' action='order.php'>
<div class='col-lg-4'>
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
<div class='panel-heading'>
<h3 class='panel-title'>$pname | ₱$pprice</h3>
</div>
<div class='panel-body'>
$pimg<hr />
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$ppid'>
<button class='btn btn-primary' name='btnaddcart' type='submit'>Order Now!</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form> ";
  }

echo "</div>";
```

When the user have chosen which one to order, he can click the order now now button and will now redirect to the **order.php** page.

And inside my order.php page it shows a table of the product he have chosen by determining it using **$_POST** on the id from menu.php.

```
$p=$_POST['id'];
$order_query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblproducts WHERE p_pid=$p");
$num_rows_order=mysqli_num_rows($order_query);

while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($order_query))
{
    $ppid=$fetch['p_pid'];
    $pname=$fetch['p_name'];
    $pprice=$fetch['p_price'];
}

foreach ($order_query as $p) {
echo "<form class='form-horizontal' action='' method='POST'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Place Order</legend>
<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>
<thead>
<tr class='success'>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class='active'>
  <td>$pname</td>
  <td>₱$pprice /each</td>
  <td><div class='form-group'>
  <div class='col-lg-4'>
    <input class='form-control' name='inputquant' value='1' type='number'>
</div>
</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
}
    ?>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <button type="submit" name="btnaddorder" class="btn btn-primary">Add More Order</button>
  </div>
       </div>
```

As you can see outside the **foreach and php** there's an **add more order button**, where the user can choose if he/she wants to add more product. What i'm trying to do is when he clicked the button, it will be redirected to the menu again and if he choose another product to add on his cart, it will be listed on the page. But when I do that, all it does is replaces the old values with the new one from clicking add more products. Its like; 'first i ordered a pizza, then decided to add a nachos. The order page shows nachos and overwrites pizza instead of showing both of them.' I have been in stuck with this problem for a while, and decided to ask here now. It would be really great if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question has many solutions. Store products selected by user in a database, store in a `$_SESSION`, whatever. It's up to you to decide.

Comment: @u_mulder whats the easiest or preferred solution do you think is the best? Since when I use session, it only saves one product. While on database, i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: There's no optimal solution. If you can't store something in a session - you obviously do it __wrong__ and can ask another question about it.

Comment: @u_mulder whenever i use session, it only saves the first and doesn't the second. If it's database, where should I start and what could I do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: does it actually redirect ?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu when i click order now from menu, yes it sends it to order.php. And the add more order button is an isset button that redirects to menu.php

Comment: is the cart user base(can the access it as a returning user)?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu what do you mean by user base?

Comment: does the cart stay same even when the leave your website (access the cart as a returning user), or just for the time frame

Comment: @ChrysUgwu its just for that session/time being. When he/she logouts it will reset back to 0

Comment: Session should be the best way around it

Comment: @ChrysUgwu i tried using session before but whenever i choose another product, the first one is the only that saves in the session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118562/discussion-between-chrys-ugwu-and-sync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**order.php**

```
//make sure session is started
$p = $_POST['id'];

//store id's as an array
$_SESSION['id'][] = $p;

//use ',' to combine id's
$p = implode(',', $_SESSION['id']);

//MySQL IN Clause
$order_query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblproducts WHERE p_pid IN ($p)");
$num_rows_order=mysqli_num_rows($order_query);
```

Comment: you think you can guide me on step by step by it, thank you so much!